# Jquery .on() keyup selector filtering

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm looking for a way to use a selector to filter results in an .on("keyup") event.  I want to be able to use selectors to determine which key is being pressed instead of creating an ever expanding if statement in the handler.  I plan on having lots of key bindings.

I want to do this:

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#canvas", "key=27", MyEscHandler);
```

instead of having to do this:

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#canvas", function (e) { 
    if(e.keyCode == 27){
        MyEscHandler(e);
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 13){

    } //and a million more of these
 });
```

Is there a way to do this? Or should I resign myself to an ever expanding switch.

Comment: There is nothing like that built in to jquery.

Comment: You're bragging, I'll bet good money you don't have a million keys on your keyboard!

Comment: If you bind 1,000,000 separate handlers instead of just one with a switch, you may find your performance suffers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty simple to write this yourself. Something like:

```
$.fn.onKeyup = function(selector, keyCode, handler) {
    $(this).on('keyup', selector, function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == keyCode) {
            handler(e);
        }
    });
};
```

Example:

```
$(document).onKeyup('#canvas', 27, function() {
    alert('Hi');
});
```